# How to remember which table row is clicked in order to display more data to another page

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I want to do next. When I click on a table row in the first HTML page, I want to display additional data for that row on another HTML page. This is the way I displayed data from PostgreSQL DB:

```
<?php
    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<tr class="click_table" data-href="bsdisplay.php" onclick="show();" style="cursor:pointer">
    <td><input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; background-color: black;"></td>
    <td><a href="bsdisplay.php" id="field" target="_blank" onclick="show();"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

The function shown is represented below:

```
function show() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "baseFunctions.php",
        success : function() { 
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

baseFunctions is another PHP page where I wrote functions to display data in bsdisplay.php. I am now trying to find a way, to remember the row that is clicked and send that information to baseFunctions page as a number. I am relatively new to all of this, so I may be complicating things more than they are. Can someone help with this way or suggest an easier way to do this?

Comment: _"baseFunctions is another php page where I wrote functions to display data in bsdisplay.php"_ - but you are not doing anything with the data your AJAX request returns, you are only reloading the current page? So what is the relation between the two supposed to be - how would the current page script incorporate the output of baseFunctions.php/bsdisplay.php?

Comment: You are using jQuery already - so you should be using jQuery's model of event handling as well, and not "old school" `onclick="show();"` attributes in the HTML. https://api.jquery.com/on/ - use that, and `$(this)` inside your callback function will give you access to the TR that the event occurred on.

Comment: Thanks. That will help I hope. On the other hand, can I somehow pass the row number that is clicked to another page?

Comment: Sure you can, go check the `data` parameter of $.ajax

Comment: `I want to display additional data for that row on another HTML page.`... the purpose of AJAX is to interact with the server _without leaving the current page_. If you want your browser to navigate to a _different_ page (i.e. bsdisplay.php) then you should probably remove the AJAX request and just let the `<a href` do its job. To let bsdisplay.php know which item was clicked, simply add a URL parameter e.g. `bsdisplay.php?id=123`, and bsdisplay.php can retrieve that with `$_GET["id"]` and then fetch the related data from your database in order to display it etc.